# Show progress bar in pop up will till page is rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have struts application, where on click on link a new window is opened. Newly opened window takes time to render contents, meantime i want to show a progress bar. I tried onLoad event of  but it's getting fired after page is rendered and i want to show progress bar from the moment window is open till contents are rendered.

Comment: you can't show anything until before the page is rendered - or at least part rendered if such a thing happens - and the progress bar ... how will the progress bar "know" how much of the page is rendered, before it's rendered?

Comment: i got it. i have some applications where same thing happens, don't know how? Is there any hack

Comment: You can directly embed the progress bar into the page and make an AJAX  call for the rest of the page content. AJAX can also be used to determine the amount of content loaded which can be used to move the progress bar.

Comment: I have a design constraint and with it i cannot use AJAX.

Comment: I am wondering what kind of design constraint that made you unable to use ajax. Is it CORS?

Answer (score 0):

Would a spinner (instead of progress bar) acceptable?

If yes, the following code will open a blank new window, show a spinner icon on that new window, load the target url in a hidden iframe. When the iframe is loaded, show the iframe and hide the spinner.

```
<button onclick="popup('http://wikipedia.com')">Pop up</button>
<script>
var myWin;
function popup(url) {
    myWin = window.open("", "_blank");
    myWin.document.write('<body style="margin:0; padding: 0; text-align: center" frameborder="0"> \
                            <iframe src="' + url + '" \
                                onload="opener.loadHandler(this)" \
                                style="display: none; position: absolute; border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%"> \
                            </iframe> \
                            <img id="spinner" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Loading_icon.gif"> \
                          </body>');
}

function loadHandler(frame) {
    frame.style.display = "block";
    myWin.document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

**UPDATE: Submitting a form**

The following code will open a blank new window, show a spinner icon on that new window, create a form in a hidden iframe, and submit it. When the iframe is loaded, show the iframe and hide the spinner.

```
<button onclick="popup('http://wikipedia.com', {foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'}, 'GET')">Pop up</button>

<script>
var myWin;
function popup(url, params, method) {
    myWin = window.open("", "_blank");
    myWin.document.write('<body style="margin:0; padding: 0; text-align: center" frameborder="0"> \
                            <iframe src="" \
                                onload="opener.loadHandler(this)" \
                                style="display: none; position: absolute; border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%"> \
                            </iframe> \
                            <img id="spinner" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Loading_icon.gif"> \
                          </body>');
    myWin.frames[0].document.body.innerHTML = createForm(url, params, method);
    myWin.frames[0].document.forms[0].submit();
}

function loadHandler(frame) {
    frame.style.display = "block";
    myWin.document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = "none";
}

function createForm(url, params, method) {
    //create a form
    var html = '<form action="' + url + '" method="' + (method || 'POST') + '">';

    //inserting params as hidden inputs
    for (var key in params) {
        var val = (params[key] || '').toString().replace(/"/, '&quot;');
        html += '<input type="hidden" name="' + key + '" value="' + val + '">';
    }
    html +=    '</form>';
    return html;
}

</script>
```

Comment: There is one catch here, In my case i need to submit form to a URL with form data. With this code i am not sure i can do that

Comment: I updated my answer with the capability to submit a form.